No download button near OS Versions in Simulator
I faced with the problem in Xcode. I can't find "Download more simulator runtimes..." button in Simulator near OS Version on my MacBook. How to add another iOS versions to my simulator? For example, I want to install iOS 17. Now I have only iOS 18
My Xcode version is 16.0


Odd. It shows up for me. Try restarting Xcode. Or go to Xcode -> Settings -> Components and add it there.

You should delete this question since it won't be helpful as-is for any future readers.
